# How to understand strict exogeneity?

Tags: difference-in-difference

Apart from paralell trend assumption, another assumption in parallel trend is **strict exogeneity**. I have read [this answer from Thomas](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/454991/what-is-the-difference-between-the-strict-exogeneity-assumption-in-ols-and-the-s) and this paper of [Miller](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10940-021-09513-w). The strict exogeneity in Miller is described in his third equation:

[image]

It seems to me that it is the additional effect of treatment group after the event date, I am wondering it is a correct thought and whether it is a must in DiD setting? Normally, I just think the parallel assumption is the main one to be satisfied before conducting a DiD test.

Comment: In equation (3) the positive values for $\gamma_s$ represent the treatment leads. In your question, though, you state that this is the additional effect of treatment "after" the event date. Could you provide clarification here? I think these refer to the periods *before* treatment actually starts.

Comment: @Thomas, yes, they said "leading" but leading in their case is later (equalling to lag in normal understanding) "**be tested by including leading (i.e., later) measures**". I am quite confused here.