# Difference in Differences when treatment ends before the end of the sample

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference

Say, if the $T_t$ (time) dummy begins as $T_t=0$ then turns into $T_t=1$ when we have the treatment period and then goes again into $T_t=0$, how does the interpretation of the interaction term change ($D_iT_t$, when $D_i$ is the dummy for the units that received the treatment)?

In such situation, what would be (in general) the more adequate model in place of the DD?

Comment: Related question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225145/difference-in-difference-with-multiple-period-pre-during-and-post-treatment).

Comment: So I would just add an interaction between the post treatment period and the treated units dummy, $D_i$?

Comment: Yes, and also a post-treatment $t_{3}$ dummy.