# diff in diff using time dummies instead of post

Tags: difference-in-difference

$$
y_{it} = \beta0\ + \beta1\cdot treat\ + beta2\cdot post+\sum_{j\neq k} \delta_j \left( \text{treat}_i \cdot year(t=j) \right) + X'\gamma + \epsilon_t
$$

time periods t=1,2,...,k,...,T periods where the treatment happens between k and k+1 (so time k is my last pre-treatment period)

I'm trying regression as mentioned above and I have few questions:

1) First is it possible to see the control group trend through this regression results?

2) Is it possible to get the total impact on Y? from the regression I get the results of T-k different coefficient, can I say what is the total impact of treatment over Y?

Comment: Please start by considering whether the model equation is correctly specified. You can find some guidance here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76058/specifying-a-difference-in-differences-model-with-multiple-time-periods?rq=1. I can spot several potential problems with the specification.

Comment: @ytz Hi. I agree. Did you reproduce this equation from a paper? If so, please provide a reference.

Comment: Hi, its not from any paper its for a work i'm doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your notation is a bit clunky but I can work with it for the purposes of this answer. This is the standard difference-in-differences (DiD) estimator with multiple pre- and post-exposure periods. Instead of indexing the entire post-treatment epoch with one dummy, it appears you want to interact your treatment dummy with *separate* post-treatment *year* indicators. Here is what I think you want to do:

$$
y_{it} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}\text{Treat}_{i} + \sum_{j \neq k} \lambda_{j} \text{Year}_{t=j} + \sum_{j \neq k} \delta_j \left( \text{Treat}_i \cdot \text{Year}_{t=j} \right) + X_{it}'\gamma + \epsilon_{it},
$$

where the $\delta_{j}$'s are separate estimates of your treatment effect for each individual treatment year. As per your post, you consider $j \leq  k$ as your *pretreatment* epoch. All periods $j$ not equal to $k$ are thus representative of post-treatment period dummies. Each coefficient on $\delta_{j}$ is an estimate of the $j$-th additive *yearly* treatment effect.

Note, I replaced the variable $\text{Post}_{t}$ with a series of post-treatment year dummies. This is *not* a full set of $T - 1$ dummies for years; rather, they are separate dummies for post-exposure years. In standard software, interacting $\text{Treat}_{i}$ with a series of post-treatment indicators will automatically result in the estimation of the year main effects as well. If you incorporate $\text{Post}_{t}$ in your specification *before* $\text{Year}_{t}$, your model will likely exclude one year to allow for the estimation of the post-treatment variable. However, if you include $\text{Post}_{t}$ *after* the individual year dummies, then software will likely drop the $\text{Post}_{t}$ variable entirely. The variable $\text{Post}_{t}$ is a linear combination of the post-treatment year dummies, and most software packages are smart enough to have quick fixes for it. In R for instance, variable ordering matters when faced with collinearity.

I would drop $\text{Post}_{t}$ entirely and replace it with separate indicators for years (i.e., post-exposure dummies).

> 1) First is it possible to see the control group trend through this regression results?

I am not sure what you mean when you say "see" the control group trend. Ideally, you should have plotted the evolution of the *trends* in your treatment and control group to assess the validity of this approach. If you are referring to the point estimates, then I believe you are referring to the individual year dummies (i.e., post-treatment dummies). Because this is an interaction model, the time dummies represent the individual pre-post differences in units **not** exposed to treatment (i.e., $\text{Treat}_{i} = 0$). Put more simply, the classical DiD *time* variable is the time trend in the *control group*. In most applications, $\delta_{j}$ *should* be your focus; this is your DiD coefficient(s).

> 2) Is it possible to get the total impact on Y? from the regression I get the results of T-k different coefficient, can I say what is the total impact of treatment over Y?

The total impact of the treatment is the interaction of your treatment dummy with $one$ post-treatment indicator. Your formulation is now more concise:

$$
y_{it} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}\text{Treat}_{i} + \lambda \text{Post}_{t} + \delta (\text{Treat}_i \cdot \text{Post}_{t}) + X_{it}'\gamma + \epsilon_{it},
$$

where $\text{Post}_{t}$ is no longer representative of *individual* dummies. It is one unique dummy indexing *all* post-treatment periods. To put this in perspective, suppose you observe each cross-sectional unit from 2010 to the present year. And, suppose treatment begins in 2016 and remains in place for the entire observation period. A single post-treatment dummy is equal to 1 in all the years treatment is in effect in *both* treatment and control groups. This is a dummy equal to 1 from 2016 onward, irrespective of a unit's group status. However, in the previous formulation, we included multiple additive year effects: a dummy for 2016, a dummy for 2017, a dummy for 2018, so on and so forth. Each is uniquely interacted with the treatment dummy.

The second specification is typically where you should start. Your estimate of $\delta$ is the total effect of the treatment/intervention. The first equation can be viewed as an *extension* of the second equation, whereby we investigate possible effect heterogeneity throughout the post-treatment period. Effects may grow or fade over time.

Comment: I have performed the first resgression as suggested:   

1. What is the meaning of the coefficient b0 and b1?    
I know that the meaning in regular pre-post regression but not sure what is the meaning in this case.  
  
2. Just to be sure, there is no way I can sum what is the total influence of the treatment over Y? I can just tell what is the treatment effect in a specific year?
3. What is the meaning of gamma? how the specific characteristic I added effected Y?