# difference-in-differences with multiple time periods - parallel trend assumption

Tags: regression, econometrics, difference-in-difference

I am performing this resgression: 
$$
y_{it} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}\text{Treat}_{i} + \sum_{j \neq k} \lambda_{j} \text{Year}_{t=j} + \sum_{j \neq k} \delta_j \left( \text{Treat}_i \cdot \text{Year}_{t=j} \right) + X_{it}'\gamma + \epsilon_{it}.  
$$

Yit - is a binary variable
time periods t=1,2,...,k,...,T
the treatment happens between k and k+1 (so time k is my last pre-treatment period).

My question is how to present to parallel trend assumption.
I understand that there are 2 methods:
1. If coefficients δ before treatment are essentially zero.
(If I get this right the 2 option are  that they are equal or close to 0 and statistically significant or they are not equal to 0 and not statistically significant).
2. Run the regression separately for the treatment and control groups. Instead of a series of treat*quarter coefficients, we have just quarter coefficients for each group, and then plot those on the same graph.

Do I understand it correctly? what is the proper way to present it?

would appreciate your help, Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both methods are doing something very similar: comparing trends between treatment and control. The first has the advantage of being able to easily test the joint null that all the pre $\delta$s are zero, rather than just comparing the coefficients visually, one by one. Moreover, the pooled model will probably yield more precise estimates than two separate models.

The second might be easier to explain to folks that don't understand interactions and makes it easier to plot the coefficients (rather than their difference).

Comment: Thank you! so is it correct I should check if the coefficients δ before treatment are equal or close to 0 and statistically significant or they are not equal to 0 and not statistically significant? I saw in some places that they should only be not statistically significant. now i'm a bit confused

Comment: The size and insignificance are related. The null would be that $\delta_1 =\delta_2 =...=\delta_{k}=0$, and if you reject, you don't have parallel trends (sort of). You want them all to be zeros, or least not significantly differently from zero given their size and SEs. It would be hard for them to be zero and significantly different from zero at the same time.

Comment: I get δ that are in the range of [-0.014,-0.004] none of them is statistically significant. are they different enough from 0 to say that the parallel trend exist?

Comment: Like I said, you need to do a joint test that they are all zero and report the p-value. The individual tests are suggestive, but not quite the thing you want here.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Good information. I was curious about assessing equivalence of the groups trends with a binary outcome. Is it enough to assess the relative *proportions* over time. I never found much guidance myself online. I was curious what your take is on plotting with binary outcomes. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ThomasBilach This model here is for $E[Y \vert X]$, which is a proportion when the outcome is binary. The $\delta$ coefficients here correspond to differences in time FEs between treatment and control. I think when you plot individual binary data the plot does get messy, but here you are not plotting the raw data.

Comment: But if I see parallel trend between coefficient in the second method I offered I can still say that the parallel trend assumption exist?

Comment: The second method does not let you conduct a hypothesis test, so it cannot be definitive. It’s like if you do 100 coin tosses and see 54 heads. Can you conclude that the coin is biased, without doing the test?

Comment: I performed the joint test that are coefficient are zero using "linearHypothesis" command in R. I got Pr(>F) = 0.9771. In his case I reject the null Hypothesis because p_value > 0.05 and the parallel trend does not exist?

Comment: You really need to spend some time reviewing the basics of hypothesis testing. You reject the null when the p-value is small. Your data is consistent with parallel trends since your p-value is quite large.

Comment: Yes, correct. Thank you!!!

Comment: I have another question. what is the interpretation when the coefficients δ before treatment are close to zero and not statistically significant?

Comment: This means you have similar pre trends between T and C. You actually need trends to be similar in the periods after treatment if there was no treatment, which is not testable since you don’t get to observe that state of the world. However, seeing it in the pre periods usually makes you believe that it would have held in the post in the absence of treatment.